# Changing the arrow/icon colour material ui select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change my icon to white  [image]

Here is my current code but not sure how to change icon colour property:

Link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-forked-cmd5g?file=/src/App.js) sample

```
 <NativeSelect
    
      disableUnderline
      style={{
        paddingLeft: 10,
        borderRadius: 20,
        color: "white",
        background: "#121c30",
        boxShadow: "0px 5px 8px -3px rgba(99,0,0,0.14)",
      }}
      
      defaultValue={"Last 7 days"}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      ......

    </NativeSelect>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The material provides you, one class, for changing the color of that icon.

```
.MuiNativeSelect-icon {
   color: red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const MyIcon = (props)=> {
    const { style, ...otherProps } = props;
    const colorStyle = {
        color: 'white',
    };
    const styles = { ...style, ...colorStyle };
    return <ArrowDropDownIcon {...otherProps} style={styles} />
}

<NativeSelect
  IconComponent={MyIcon}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to use inline styles, as you cannot apply them in classes property, in your case this should work for you

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  iconSelect: {
    color: "white"
  },
});

...
export default function App() {
   const classes = useStyles();
   ...
   <NativeSelect
          disableUnderline
          classes={{icon: classes.iconSelect}}
          ...
        >
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/table-forked-7w6nw

Answer (score 0):

Create .css, where  is your choice.
there. instead of writing: `color:white;` you can write `color:white !important;`